# Wrong format by ddwrt:Today()

Tags: date-time, xml

I made a display form for my list and I had to insert the current date into text. I found this code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:Today()"/>
```

and it's working, but in Designer I see correct format (DD.MM.YYYY), but on website I see MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Everything local setups are Czech. Do you know some solutions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "FormatDateTime". In my case would be:

```
ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(ddwrt:Today()),1033,'dd')
```

This link may be helpful too: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

I hope this helps.